# 1.16.4 - How to show the mob's health above his head?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My objective is to create a health bar above the mob's head, and I was thinking about storing the data in a sign, and then setting the mob's CustomName to the sign Text1, but this way I would need a sign for each mob of my world.

Answer (score 2):

## Edit

`/scoreboard` could help.

```
scoreboard objectives add health health
# Put the following in a repeating command block
execute as @e[tag=track_health] run data merge @s {CustomName:'{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"health"}}'}
```

## Old answers

```
data merge entity @e[tag=track_health,limit=1] {CustomName:'{"nbt":"Health","entity":"@e[tag=track_health,limit=1]"}'
```

```
setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:sign{Text1:'{"nbt":"Health","entity":"@e[tag=track_health,limit=1]"}'}
```

Comment: The /data merge didn't work, I will write exactly what I did:
/summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1b,Silent:1b,CustomNameVisible:1b,Tags:[test]}
Then, in an Always active Repeating command block I wrote: /data merge entity @e[tag=test,limit=1] {CustomName:'{"nbt":"Health","entity":"@e[tag=test,limit=1]"}'}
btw I am playing in 1.16.4

Comment: The zombie is tagged incorrectly; use `Tags:["test"]`

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. `Tags:[test]` is invalid NBT syntax. Also, the repeating command block isn't needed as with the raw JSON text it will automatically update the name

Comment: still the same problem, his name is just a blank space.

Comment: I tried to replace "entity" with "selector", and now his name is @e[tag=test,limit=1]. While doing this, I found out that if I type random words instead of "entity", it has the same result, looks like "entity" is not valid. I remember that in a video the guy explained that you can't do this with entities, so I think I have to use this command in a sign, and then, another command that takes from the sign and gives to the mob. But with this metod, I would need a sign for each mob.

Comment: @AruBr I highly doubt it. The Minecraft Wiki states that `entity` is valid. The problem could be that Minecraft isn't able to interpret a `TAG_Float` as a `TAG_String`, but I'm not sure. So if my method doesn't work, neither will the sign method; it's also going to attempt and fail to interpret a `TAG_Float` as a `TAG_String`. However, there might be another way. I'm editing my answer, hopefully this will work.

Comment: The scoreboard method had the same result as the other, I think all this problem is because the entity can't get information from his or other entities' nbt. The sign method is a command that that /setblocks a sign with the Text1 to the nbt (and this works well), and then the mob takes the information from the block, so if you use your sign command and then this one: `/execute as @e[tag=test] run data modify entity @s CustomName set from block x y z Text1`, the mob's health float above his head, just like I want, but this way I would need so many signs. I don't know the reason, but this works.